# Why does M2 place all CSS in inline <style> tags in the header?

Tags: magento2, configuration, css, less

I've set up a site and I must have some strange configurations, because ALL applied styles on the entire site are coming from inline  tags in the header:

[image]

If you check the markup it comes from this element with a strange ID:

[image]

I have never seen anything like this in M2 yet.

How and why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is for developer/debugging use only, once you are running with server-side compilation and in production mode you should no longer see them.

This is a screenshot from a production website we have:

[image]

Comment: I'll second that, production mode you'll no longer see it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used custom js such as LeaVerou prefixfree, that convert link stylesheet tag to style tag. This was what happened to me.